# QGIS identify features button issue

Tags: qgis, features, layers

Is there anyway to get the Identify Features button in QGIS to automatically select a layer and provide the information without having to highlight it first in the layers TOC?

MapInfo and ArcGIS automatically highlight, but can't see that QGIS does.

Comment: Welcome to the site! If your question has been answered please consider accepting the answer, to help others who may have the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there is. Go to `Options` in the `Settings` menu and open the tab `Map tools`.

Then you can set the `Identify Mode`. You probably want the `Top down, stop at first`.

Comment: That setting doesn't seem to exist any more, although there are other "Identify" options on the Map Tools tab, still.