# Selecting/ Deselecting and Identifying Features in QGIS

Tags: qgis, select, identify

I am new to QGIS.

I have a large ArcMap project that I can access in QGIS for reference, so I will only really be using it to identify features. For example to check the classification of a road line (which may be correct even if a lozenge on a map is incorrect, for example.)

I have my project open, but am unable to select any features from layers that are checked.

I only have the option to Deselect Features from All Layers. However, when I try to do that, nothing seems to happen. So I am unable to select any features that I want to identify.

Comment: If you are happy with the answer / it solved the problem please could you accept an answer so it shows as being a completed question. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike ArcMap you need to have the layer you want to identify highlighted in the table of contents as well as turned on. I think the deselect feature isn't doing anything if you don't currently have any layers selected.
Also see this answer:
[QGIS identify features button issue](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34194/qgis-identify-features-button-issue)

Answer (score 2):

Not to contradict the above answer but you do not need to have the layer you want to identify ticked. Well not entirely. If it is select then yes but the question seems to lead to interrogating the data.

If you want to interrogate the data click the i button.  Ensure that in settings > options > map tools that you have selected top down in the identify box.

This works for interrogating data NOT selecting.

Comment: You are correct in saying that there is a possible alternative method - however it is covered in the link I included in my answer.

Comment: Sorry. Did not go into the link. My apologies.