# Identify features problem in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, point-in-polygon, identify

[image]I am using QGIS 2.18 to identify points that fall out of a specific boundary but the identify features is not working. When I right click, it brings me the polygon feature. So i turned off the polygon layer and highlighted the layer i am working with as described in [QGIS identify features button issue](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34194/qgis-identify-features-button-issue) but it is still not working. I found the identify mode in the map tools but cant seem to figure out what: "You probably want the Top down, stop at first" means. It is either it does not bring up the table at all or the identify results table is blank. I have also tried this in QGIS 3.4 and got the same results. Some points are identified while some are not.

Comment: Have you tried selecting said points and checking their attributes in the table?

Comment: the points are actually from different shapefiles that is why I opted for using identify features for unique distinction

Comment: Sounds to me like you hadn't selected the correct layer after all?

Comment: I wish I could attach a screenshot but there is no option for that here. So i am trying to identify points that fall out of my specified boundary by using select features using an expression which turns the features selected yellow. For the ones that fall out of my specified boundary, I clicked on the identify features icon and right click on the point in question to see its attributes with the same layer still selected but for some points, when I right click, nothing pops up

Comment: When editing your post, the sixth symbol from the left above the textfield allows you to add images.

Comment: Thank you for this, I have added a snapshot

Comment: Are both points on the same layer?

Comment: yes both points are on the same layer.

Comment: Have you verified that the point without feedback has a valid geometry and also attributes stored?

Comment: yes I have. Instead of randomly clicking on icons in the attribute table till the point I am looking for is highlighted, I decided to use the identify feature which is faster

Comment: You may select features on the map instead of in the attribute table, and choose to display these selected features on top of the attribute table (blue-white-yellow icon with a blue arrow). Could you provide said two points as an example?